# MySQL, bind-address, Windows, Error 1067 my.ini

Tags: windows, mysql, configuration, settings

I trying to set alternate IP for gain access to MySQL Server (accessing from a PC with IP 192.168.1.20) in the file:
**my.ini**

MySQL starts without problem, when in the configuration file, in the section *mysqld* I have:

```
[mysqld]
...
bind-address=0.0.0.0
```

But, does not starts when in the configuration file, in the section *mysqld* I have:

```
[mysqld]
...
bind-address=192.168.1.20 #Remote IP of Client PC
```

Showing the error code 1067:

With bind-address=0.0.0.0, all remote IP's are enable to gain access to my MySQL Server, I want to restrict only to 192.168.1.20.

How Can I fix this, or what is my mistake?

BR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't bind to a remote IP address because bind assigns the local address to a socket, which must either be a local address or a wildcard. I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but whatever it is, that's not the way to do it.